# CommandArgument is empty from jquery table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to create delete functionality for a jquery table Datatables.net and call the C# method. It seems I can't pass the row id value to the server. Any ideas?

```
               {
                    'data': "docid",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (data != null)
                            console.log(row.docid);
                        return '<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" CommandArgument=' + row.docid  + ' CommandName="btnclick" OnClick="DeleteRequest" />'

     
                    }
                },



protected void DeleteRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    switch (btn.CommandName)
    {
        case "btnclick":
            obj.deleteRequestDraft(Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument.ToString()));
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: `<asp:Button ID="test" runat="` is never going to work, given that JS is a client side concern. JS can't render a server-side control like that.

Comment: But it is working where I managed to call the server-side method. Just that the btn.CommandArgument.ToString() is empty..

Comment: Please view source in the browser and show us what the `return '<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" CommandArgument=' + row.docid  + ' CommandName="btnclick" OnClick="DeleteRequest" />'` line looks like **in the HTML**.

Comment: return '<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$test" value="" id="MainContent_test" />'

Comment: So, as you can see - the `CommandArgument` has been lost.

Comment: Somehow can only see btn.CommandArgument.ToString() = "' + row.docid  + '" in the backend

Answer (score 0):

had you tried this?
[datatable][1]

[1]: [https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()#:~:text=remove()%20](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()#:%7E:text=remove()%20))%20will%20remove%20the,called%20to%20update%20the%20display.

Comment: Please explain what the link leads to and how it is related to the question; don't just post a link without any other explanation.